# Microchip PIC period register PR2

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip

From Microchip sample code

```
PR2 = 2083u;     /* Timer2 Period, 19.2 kHz */
```

How does `2083u` correspond to 19.2 kHz, which is

```
1 / 19.2E03 = 52.083u
```

They don't correspond at all. Mistake by Microchip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PR2 = 2083U
```

makes TIMER2 trigger every 2083 CPU cycles. Calculating

```
52.083 us / 2083 = 25 ns
1 / 25 ns = 40 MHz
```

we can conclude that the processor is probably running at `FCY = 40 MHz` in the example.

The letter `u` in `PR2 = 2038u;` does not mean microseconds; it is a C language syntax that makes the integer literal unsigned. See [Signedness (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness).

Answer (score 0):

Setting PR2 to 2083 means that the timer triggers every 2084 (not 2083) clock cycles. When you calculate a timer period, you always have to subtract 1 because the timer value is zero-based.